# Ajax ’load more’ function does not proper load colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, colorbox

I’ve created a “load more” link which loads the next 100 entries via a AJAX call.
My AJAX call looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function HideButton(){
        $('#load_post').css('display', 'none')
     }
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<div class='loading_wrapper'><img class='loading' src='<?php echo url(); ?>images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' /></div>";
    var loadUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com/loadmore.php";

    $("#load_post").click(function(){
        $("#result")
            .html(ajax_load)
            .load(loadUrl, {exclude: "<?php echo $exclude_more_post_str; ?>"},
            function() {
            $('#load_post').css('display', 'none');
            });
    });
</script>
```

The loadmore.php codes just retrieve the next 100 entries from the database, which is pretty much the same query as the main page just with an offset.

It loads correctly the 100 entries but it does not load it into my colorbox iframe. The first entries, before loading more via AJAX, works fine but the 100 entries loaded by AJAX don’t load the page inside the colorbox even though it has the right class attached to the **a href**.

When pressing an entry which should be opened in a colorbox iframe it just show the page, e.g. http://www.mydomain.com/single-entry/this-is-the-post-suppose-to-open-in-colorbox/

Is there some special property I have missed when running the AJAX call so I need to reload the colorbox. I’ve tried to but the Colorbox javascript in both the header and the footer but the result is the same.

If I’ve explained myself unclear, please let me know and I’ll try to clarify.

Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  You said you are using colorbox with an iframe.  Where is that?  Are you trying to inject html into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the content of loadmore.php, or other url, into a colorbox iframe try changing the href attribute of its plugin container (i.ex: `<a class="loadmore" href=""/>`... or whatever you call it) and throw the click event (if previously initialized).

```
$("#load_post").click(function(){
        $(".loadmore").attr('href', "http://www.mydomain.com/loadmore.php").click();
    });
```

You could even chain the initializing method over .loadmore tag like that:

```
  $("#load_post").click(function(){
            $(".loadmore").attr('href', "http://www.mydomain.com/loadmore.php")
.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"}).click();
        });
```

I hope it will